Can we run Docker in Docker based on Ubuntu22.04?
We are trying to run Docker inside docker container hosted on top of AKS v1.27.
This was working on Ubuntu18 based image, but not working same way on Ubuntu22.04.
The issue is that Docker is not getting started on this created sclaedjob contianers, where as manually executing the command inside the container "service docker start" starting the docker service. Also when we run docker.sh first time in the container getting below error, but when rerun again second time same script, starting the docker service.
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Base image as below
FROM ubuntu:22.04
#2-Enable Ubuntu Packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    wget \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
#install docker daemon inside docker
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg |  gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
RUN echo \
   "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io -y

WORKDIR /azp
COPY ./vstsagent/ .
COPY ./start.sh .
COPY ./docker.sh .
RUN chmod +x start.sh docker.sh
CMD ["./docker.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["./start.sh"]


The ado Image created from above base image as below..

FROM myregistry/agetImage
RUN apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io -y
COPY ./daemon.json /etc/docker/
COPY ./config.json /root/.docker/
WORKDIR /azp/
RUN rm -rf start.sh 
COPY ./start.sh .
RUN rm -rf docker.sh
COPY ./docker.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/ulimit -Hn/# ulimit -Hn/g' /etc/init.d/docker
RUN chmod 777 start.sh
RUN chmod 777 docker.sh
RUN usermod -aG docker root
ENV AGENT_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="true"
CMD ["./docker.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT [ "./start.sh"]


docker.sh as below

#!/bin/bash
echo "DOCKER STARTS HERE"
service docker start
docker version
docker ps


daemon.json as below
{
    "storage-driver": "vfs"
}


scaledjob as below

apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledJob
spec:
  jobTargetRef:
    template:
      spec:
        affinity:
          nodeAffinity:
            preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - preference:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: kubernetes.azure.com/mode
                  operator: Exists
                  values:
                  - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                - key: topology.disk.csi.azure.com/zone
                  operator: Exists
                  values:
                  - westeurope-2
              weight: 2
        containers:
        - name: xxxxxxxxxxxx
          image: myregistry/vstsnew/vsts_customxxxx
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1500m
              memory: 10Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 6Gi
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
            privileged: true
          env:
          - name: AZP_URL
            value: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
          - name: AZP_TOKEN
            value: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
          - name: AZP_POOL
            value: xxxxxxxxxxxx
          - name: AZP_AGENT_NAME
            value: DockerAgentLinux
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /mnt
            name: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        nodeSelector:
          agentpool: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        volumes:
        - name: xxxxxxxx
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  pollingInterval: 30
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 5
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 5
  maxReplicaCount: 6
  minReplicaCount: 1
  scalingStrategy:
    strategy: "default"
  triggers:
  - type: azure-pipelines
    metadata:
      poolID: "xxxx"
      organizationURLFromEnv: "AZP_URL"
      personalAccessTokenFromEnv: "AZP_TOKEN"


When you have both an ENTRYPOINT and a CMD, the ENTRYPOINT command is run and the CMD is appended to it as parameters. So in your case, the command that's run when the container starts is ./start.sh ./docker.sh. It looks like you expect both scripts to be run, but that's not how Docker works.

But the same Dockerfile is worked for my ubuntu18.04. So What I am expecting is, Docker  should be started inside the container, and here start.sh is the starter script for the Azuredevops agent.

Commands like service don't usually work in containers; it's not usually a best practice to try to run multiple processes in a single container.  Can you run a separate container running the unmodified docker:dind image?  Using Docker-in-Docker at all isn't usually recommended, since the Docker daemon requires elevated privileges in a couple of ways; can you use the Kubernetes API in AKS, or restructure your application to not need direct access to the container system at all?

I tried, but that also didnt help me as container went to completed status after the command execution and it didnt run.

Moreover how this is working on ubuntu 18.04 then ?
